# Transaction Too Large

Tags: solana, trustwallet, staking

I unstaked my Solana on TrustWallet from 5 or so delegators at once. Since then, when I go to claim my rewards, I receive the following error:

> encoded solana_sdk::transaction::versioned::Versioned-Transaction too large: 1876 bytes (max: encoded/raw 1683/1232).

There's no option to separate the transactions in TrustWallet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same issue. The problem is that Trust Wallet tries to claim from all validators at once, creating a larger than accepted transaction payload.

From [Solana's website](https://solana.com/docs/programs/deploying):

> a limitation of Solana transactions having a maximum serialized size of 1232 bytes.

So the issue needs to be solved by Trust, nothing Solana can do about this.
I reached out to customer support, but they just gave me a standard reply to update the app and make sure I have enough free SOL for transaction fees, which I do and has nothing to do with this error.
This is really annoying - the funds are stuck in the app while the price is in a freefall.
I'm trying to press them to open a bug ticket and solve this with the next update, but no reply yet.

Comment: No help from customer support, but I reached out to the team on github and they confirmed that the issue will be solved with the next release

Comment: Your findings are consistent with my research.  Totally sucks having this SOL locked-up while the coin is in freefall.  Any word on when the next update will be?

Comment: Any updates on this? I am still having the same issue and getting nowhere with TrustWallet.